# swift: setting back button image in nav bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I'm trying to set the back button image in nav bar in my controller, here's my code in viewDidLoad():

```
        var backImg: UIImage? = UIImage(named: "back_btn.png")
    println(backImg)
    if var back_img = backImg  {
        println("GET IT")
        println(back_img)
        println(UIControlState.Normal)
        println(UIBarMetrics.Default)
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem.backBarButtonItem.setBackButtonBackgroundImage(back_img, forState: UIControlState.Normal, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    }
```

I tried to put them to viewWillLoad, but getting the same error

Console with error message:

```
<UIImage: 0x7ff37bd85750>
GET IT
<UIImage: 0x7ff37bd85750>
VSC14UIControlState (has 1 child)
(Enum Value)
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I don't know which part went wrong. Seems like the back_img is not nil, but I got error saying it's nil

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have figured out by looking into sample code.
1) Create a bar button item in storyboard.
2) Link that button to controller using IBOutlet
3) Add image to the button

```
 var backImg: UIImage = UIImage(named: "back_btn")
 backBtn.setBackgroundImage(backImg, forState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)
```

PS: image should be added to Images.xcassets folder, see sample code, [UICatalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/UICatalog-Swift/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014577) , for details.

Comment: Hello, my image is stretched for some reason. What is the size of your image?

Comment: Image is stretched because of the space allocated to the bar item by default. One way to get around this is to select the navigation item in storyboard and put a single space in 'Back Button' text box. Then, when you set an image it is limited to the remaining space...an alternative is to set a UIButton as the BarButton item.

Comment: @goggelj, i have already set one space in storyboard in navigation bar -> back button.
but image is stretched again. do you have any solution for that ?

Comment: @mehul, If you have a bar item (inside bar button item) on the nav bar, select it and make sure it has a space too in 'title'

Comment: @goggelj, thanks but i have checked and thanks for solution. thanks.

Answer (score 24):

In **Swift 3.0 +** put below code in `appdelegate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, it will work perfectly

```
let backImage = UIImage(named: "BackNavigation")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = backImage
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backImage
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, -80.0), for: .default)
```

Or for **Swift 4.0 +**

```
let backImage = UIImage(named: "back-icon").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = backImage
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backImage
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -80.0), for: .default)
```

The last line will remove the title of `Navigation Back Button` if you don't want to remove title then just remove last line

Comment: Hey, I tried the above solution and the background image remained unchanged. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Tristan please share your code snippet if not working also try to make sure you have added "back-icon" image in your solution ?

Answer (score 17):

If you want to change the back button in every controller you can add this to app delegate in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
    let backImg: UIImage = UIImage(named: "back_button")!
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonBackgroundImage(backImg, forState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)
```

Comment: @ChanchalRaj UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, -60), for: UIBarMetrics.default) this will do the trick

Answer (score 12):

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "back-icon")
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "back-icon")
```

Answer (score 6):

//Here is the perfect solution To Set back button with Image and Action in default Navigation Bar

*First add UIBarButton in Navigation bar*

[image]

*Then Go to property in File inspector in storyboard and add space to hide back button title text*

*Set image in Ui Bar button image*

[image]

/*Write on click action method*/

**To enable swipe to pop (back to previous controller), write two line code in ViewDidLoad method**

[image]

*And you will get perfect Back Button with Swipe to back animation*

[image]

//Note:- To disable back button previous viewcontroller title , add one space in title text in back button in storyboard file inspector

Comment: Please include searchable and selectable text for code instead of an image.

Answer (score 1):

alternative way:
click on the navigation controller in storyboard (not the navigation controller in the UIViewController itself). Then, in the attributes section on the RHS you'll see back image and back mask. Set back image and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4+ version**

```
let backImage = UIImage(named: "back-icon").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = backImage
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backImage
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -80.0), for: .default)
```