# How to customize UItoolbar

Tags: ios, swift, uitoolbar

Twitter Registration Page

[image]

Hi everyone I have some cushions about UItoolBar on swift 3/4

I'm trying to make an singIn design like twitter,

1) i create toolbar with code;

```
let toolBar = UIToolbar()
toolBar.sizeToFit()

let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.done, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneClicked))


toolBar.setItems([flexibleSpace, doneButton], animated: false)
kullaniciAdi.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
eposta.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
sifre.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
```

but I can't add custom buttons on that. Like changing the "Done" text in my language.

2) So I created manually using Storyboard a toolBar with inside a button and Flexible Space. But ı need to "attach" that toolbar to the keyboard, so when i start to edit the textfield the toolbar will automatically show up. NOTE: it will be fantastic if the toolbar will show too when not-editing textField. Like that:

My app trying too attach toolbar

[image]

THANK YOU ALL

Comment: Do u want change title in first one??

Comment: yes please. Thank you

Comment: U can chk, how to customise , UIBarbutton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Code

```
let sonrakiButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Sonraki", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.sendDoneBtnAction))
```

For more info, read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23904848/how-to-add-toolbar-above-keyboard)

Comment: thank you very very muck, can I change the background color too? and the .layer.cornerRadius? and the color?

Comment: U may go with that link.

Comment: i want to customize the button... not the toolbar

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499998/how-to-set-image-for-bar-button-with-swift