# Add PDF image to UIBarItem Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Is it possible to use a PDF image, or other vector formats, in a `UIBarItem`? 
Every time that I'm applying one .png I'm losing a lot of quality for so small pics (30x26 pixels).

If yes, can you give me a code explanation on how can I implement it? Should I create a reference to my bar?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the pdf images in the assets.xcassets and Xcode will generate the 1x, 2x and 3x images at the compile time.

You can fetch the image like this: `let image = UIImage(named: "imageName")`

Comment: But can I pass the UIImage to the bar button isn’t it?

Comment: Yes, you can pass the image name from the storyboard or through the code too. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499998/how-to-set-image-for-bar-button-with-swift

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was what I needed ! ;)