# Customised navigation bar back button title

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I want customised navigation bar back button title with action.

My Image :

[image]

I need back button like this. Here i added text successfully, but not back arrow. Here my code has action for back button.

This is my code

```
    //Custom barButtonItem with custom alert function
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "< Dialer", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(back(sender:)))
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton
```

When i add above code it's getting like this.
[image]

Comment: I tried `NSMutableAttributedString` but it's not working. My code is `let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "<",
                                                   attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)])
        attrString.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string: " Dialer",
                                                    attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 36)]))`

Comment: `let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "\(attrString)", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(back(sender:)))`

Comment: This code helps a lot for me ....   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499998/how-to-set-image-for-bar-button-with-swift/35233701

Answer (score 0):

```
func backButtonConfiguration(_ title : String, backImageName : String) {
    let backImage : UIImage = UIImage(named: backImageName)!
    self.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = backImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    self.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backImage
    self.navigationBar.backItem?.title = title
}
```

**Update**

if we need custom action for back button then we have to add custom BarButtonItem. And if we need bar back button look same as built in back button then we can create custom view and use it it as a bar button item

```
  weak var customView : UIView!

  lazy var leftBarButtonView : UIBarButtonItem! = {
    let btnBack = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customView)
    let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(btnButtonClicked(_:)))
    gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.customView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    self.customView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return btnBack
  }()

  @objc func btnButtonClicked(_ gesture : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
  }

 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [leftBarButtonView]
```

Comment: How to add action for back button, when I click back button I want to show some alert . if user clicked yes then only I want to go back .

Comment: then create a custom UIButton with title and image. then create UIBarButtonItem with UIBarButtonItem(customView: customButton)

Comment: @ jpulikkottil, Here I already added custom UIBarButtonItem , we need to set customised text for that UIBarButtonItem.

Comment: Here what is the custom view

Comment: customView is UIView, Which design with image and lable. Same as inbuilt back button.