# iOS 13 - UIBarButtonItem size too small

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uistoryboard, ios13

I'm updating my app to iOS 13 and my UIBarButtonItems are smaller.

iOS 13 screenshot:

[image]

iOS 12 screenshot:

[image]

Take a look at the pause icon. It's smaller.

My code:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay target:self action:@selector(botaoPressionado:)];
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: can you show the code of how you add the graphic to the UIBarButtonItem ?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann added!

Comment: This feels like a potential autolayout/constraints problem.  But anyways, that one line doesn't help me too much, I'd love to see a few more lines of code (e.g. how do you assign the normal sized right bar button item, too; and how do you set up the two buttons on either side of the slider).

Comment: @ErickSasseFilho
I think it's native behaviour so we can not change I think. You may need to use image for iOS 13.
UIBarButtonItem.init(image: UIImage(named: "play.png"), style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)

Comment: In the images you attached, the icons are the exact same size. Only the bar height is larger on the iOS 13 image. Are you sure you get smaller images?

Comment: Perhaps a non-issue with the new SFSymbols? If you adjust your systems font size do the icons adjust?

Comment: @DanielStorm the icons don't adjust. Is there a way to force large icons programatically?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann it's an array of buttons. The volume bar has a fixed size depending on device's width.

Comment: @MiteshPrajapati I tried setting a image but wasn't able to tint. Because depending on layouts color, my buttons change tint color too.

Comment: @Yonat the bottom bar is OK. I'm talking about the top toolbar. Take a look at the pause and share icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS 13 with the new SFSymbols, the icon size adjusts based on the space.

In this case, the volume bar has a fixed size, and it was too large so it was squashing the play/pause button.

Fixed it reducing the volume bar width, now it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The native images in iOS 13 has been changed. `UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay` image has been changed. Same with the second one that you have used `UIBarButtonSystemItemAction` image.

**Xcode 10 - iOS 12:**

[image]

**Xcode 11 - iOS 13:**

[image]

If you want to maintain the consistency for both iOS then add custom images in bar button.

- [How to set image for bar button with swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499998/how-to-set-image-for-bar-button-with-swift)

**EDIT**

To change the bar button Item tint color:

```
barButtonItem.tintColor = .black
```

If you want to use custom image, then set the bar button system item property custom and :

```
barButtonItem.image = UIImage(named: "imageName")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to change the image color programatically? Setting tint or something. Because depending on the color, my buttons change.

Comment: I'm asking it because I tried before and the image always kept original colors.

Comment: @ErickSasseFilho
You can change color by set tint color of UIBarButtonItem.