# Add image to Navigation Bar Back Button

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I want to have the back button with "< [IMG]" instead of "< Back" which is by default.

```
let barAppearace = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
barAppearace.setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, -60), for:UIBarMetrics.default)
```

with this I have removed the text but how to add an image next to the "<".

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769770/swift-setting-back-button-image-in-nav-bar

Comment: But I need "<" Symbol too.

Comment: You can get the image with < symbol.

Comment: You it as a whole image.  Forget of "<" as a text.

Comment: Can't do it w/o "<" in image ? Even I thought of doing it by image only but later on if it is possible to replace it so it would have been good.

Answer (score 2):

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image:UIImage(named: "ic_authors_detail_back.png"), style:.Plain, target:self, action:"backButtonPressed");
backButton.tintColor = UIColor(hexString: "#ffffffff")
let leftBarButtonsArray = [backButton]
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = leftBarButtonsArray
```

Here is the code to add a button on navigation bar.Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

When you click left bar button

[image]

You can set its attribute like:

[image]

Here is option to set image.

Comment: I don't want to use "<" in image.

Comment: So where I am using "<" ?

Comment: This replaces whole "< Back" with image. Am I correct ? Sorry haven't tried it but I think that.

Comment: Yes, it is. But as per your requirement either you can use an image having "<" or only use that icon "<".